# bash match regexp in IF statement

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, space

Please help me to understand what is wrong. The script below all the time returns "doesn't match"

```
while true
do
        PING_OUTPUT="64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=35.2 ms"  #`ping -c 1 $PING_HOST |sed -n 2p`
        echo "$PING_OUTPUT"
        if [[ "$PING_OUTPUT" =~ 64\sbytes\sfrom\s8.8.8.8:\sicmp_seq=1\sttl=119\stime=35.2\sms ]]
        then
                echo "Match"
        else
                echo "Doesn't match"
        fi
        read -p "Where to ping?" PING_HOST
done
```

I tried different format of regexp:

```
if [[ "$PING_OUTPUT" =~ 64[ ]bytes[ ]from[ ]8.8.8.8:[ ]icmp_seq=1[ ]ttl=119[ ]time=35.2[ ]ms ]]
```

This time it shows syntax error:

```
./main_script.sh: line 10: syntax error in conditional expression
./main_script.sh: line 10: syntax error near `]bytes['
./main_script.sh: line 10: `    if [[ "$PING_OUTPUT" =~ 64[ ]bytes[ ]from[ ]8.8.8.8:[ ]icmp_seq=1[ ]ttl=119[ ]time=35.2[ ]ms ]]'
```

It looks like right side of =~ is not being interpreted as regexp, but I can't understand why.

Comment: are you trying to match `[` and `]`? Having those brackets present is going to confuse bash on where to close. If you need to match the bracket then use an escape character: `\[`.

Comment: I simplified everything giving some exact value to variable and trying to compare it with regex, but it doesn't work. Just want to understand why it doesn't work, where is the syntax problem in this simple script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash does not support `\s` since it uses POSIX regex library, this is why your first attempt failed.

---

In bash manual it reads:

> ... Any part  of  the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string...

So, just quote those spaces and it'll work. E.g:

```
PING_OUTPUT="64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=35.2 ms"  #`ping -c 1 $PING_HOST |sed -n 2p`
if [[ "$PING_OUTPUT" =~ 64" "bytes" "from" "8.8.8.8:" "icmp_seq=1" "ttl=119" "time=35.2" "ms ]]; then
    echo "Match"
else
    echo "Doesn't match"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help

Answer (score 1):

As oguzismail said bash does not support \s.

If you want to match any form of whitespace in bash use [[:space:]].

```
if [[ "$PING_OUTPUT" =~ 64[[:space:]]bytes[[:space:]]from[[:space:]]8.8.8.8:[[:space:]]icmp_seq=1[[:space:]]ttl=119[[:space:]]time=35.2[[:space:]]ms ]]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried both syntaxes with quotes(" ") and with [[:space:]] both worked for me.